# Using H2O.ai POJO/MOJO/API with popular BI tools

Tags: h2o

Installing and using H2O.ai's Flow UI is great and all - but has anyone tried to use the built models in popular BI tools like Qlik/PowerBI?

I've read a little bit on POJO/MOJO outputs, do these tools support them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Qlik/etc but I've been following the announcements from one particular vendor called Yellowfin. Their latest release seems to integrate h2o capabilities into their reporting/visualizations:

https://www.yellowfinbi.com/blog/2017/11/yellowfin-7-4-enabling-data-science-across-the-enterprise-with-h2o-ai

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

POJO (Plain old java object) and MOJO (Model ObJect, Optimized) are H2O-generated models intended to be easily embeddable in any Java environment. As far as I know neither PowerBi nor Qlik do not support export in those models. But [Apache Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark) framework can generate POJOs for sure.